# CSS3 Transition from right side of window using :target

Tags: html, css, jsfiddle

I'm am facing two issue:

Here is the jsFiddle to reference: http://jsfiddle.net/2D7Ss/1/

1. In the current jsFiddle, when the greeting box slides to the left, it appears entirely at once, instead of incrementally, before sliding to the left. The slide to the right works fine.
2. If I set the greeting div's width to 100%, it doesn't slide to the left. This issue seems related to the one above because it appears entirely in the panel before sliding. But in this case the width is 100% so no sliding occurs.

Ultimately, I'm am trying to build a page when each other page or content panel slides from the right.

Here is the HTML:

```
<a href="#hello">Hello</a> | <a href="#goodbye">Goodbye</a>
<div id="content">
    <div id="hello">Hello</div>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <div id="goodbye">Goodbye</div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
body {
  margin-left: 5px;   
}

#content {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  height: 102px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#content div {
  position: absolute;
  background: lightblue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  left: 100%;
  -moz-transition: left 1s ease;
  -webkit-transition: left 1s ease;
}

#content > div:target {
  left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems a browser issue and seems working fine with some delay and handling width together, as a workaround you can try to change left, border-width and width by transition, below is the working case tested in chrome only ([refer to the updated jsfiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/2D7Ss/39/)):

```
#content div {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: lightblue;
    width: 0px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-width: 0px;
    left: 100%;
    -moz-transition: left 1s ease, width 0s ease-out 1s, border-width 0s ease-out 1s;
    -webkit-transition: left 1s ease, width 0s ease-out 1s, border-width 0s ease-out 1s;
}
#content > div:target {
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    -moz-transition: left 1s ease 0.1s, width 0s ease-out 0.1s, border-width 0s ease-out 0.1s;
    -webkit-transition: left 1s ease 0.1s, width 0s ease-out 0.1s, border-width 0s ease-out 0.1s;
}
```

Comment: Works great thanks. Looks like the delayed width animation is the key. Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: I've searched a bit but didn't find any related document, just tried adding width animation to make it more smooth and found this workaround.